# How to scale subset of data in spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with several columns, importantly one column with a datetime stamp and another with a value.  I would like to scale all the values in the value column by a constant number if that value corresponds to a datetime that is before a certain time.

For example

```
id | datetime   | value | other_col |
1  | 2020-10-1  | 0.1   | 200       |
1  | 2020-10-20 | 0.01  | 100       |
1  | 2020-10-14 | 0.2   | 200       |
1  | 2020-10-25 | 1     | 200       |
```

should transform to

```
id | datetime   | value | other_col |
1  | 2020-10-1  | 1     | 200       |
1  | 2020-10-20 | 0.01  | 100       |
1  | 2020-10-14 | 2     | 200       |
1  | 2020-10-25 | 1     | 200       |
```

if the datetime < 2020-10-20.  Only the values in the value column should change and the rest of the dataframe should be unaltered.

I tried to do this with a map function but I am unfamiliar with spark dataframes and currently I just get one numeric output instead of the whole dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row


def scale_data(x):
    if x.datetime<= "2020-10-20 08:00:00.00":
        return x.value * 10
    return x


df2 = df.rdd.map(lambda x: Row(scale_data(x))).toDF()
```

I would like the whole dataframe returned with only the subset of data meeting the condition to have been transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the when function to get around this problem. You won't have to write UDFs that might slow the code down.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df2 = df.withColumn("scaled", when(df["datetime"] <= lit("2020-10-20 08:00:00.00"), df["value"]*lit(10))
.otherwise(df["value"])))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is it gauranteed to be more performant, if so why?  It definitely looks much cleaner.

Comment: Since the functions I used are from Spark’s own sql apis which can be optimised by spark as opposed to UDFs. These functions are translated directly to SQL relations as opposed to UDFs that aren't SQL relations

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using a user defined function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType


def scale_data(datetime, value):
    if datetime<= "2020-10-20 08:00:00.00":
        return value * 10
    else:
        return value

scale_data_UDF = udf(scale_data, DoubleType())
df2 = df.withColumn("scaled_value", scale_data_UDF(df["datetime"], df["value"]))
```